# Shortcut to set all properties in VSCode

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

[image]

I'm creating a new object that takes an object as one of the args. VSCode intellisense suggests all the possible properties the object can have. Is there a way to automatically add all the keys so I can just add the values?

Comment: not that I know of. is it really that hard to do it manually? and what do you want to happen for optional properties? your screenshot shows _only_ optional properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing *required* properties can be added by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>
 > "add missing properties".

[image: Missing properties]